# Private Forum For Moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators

Since I was just promoted to moderator status on SuperUser, I've had some inevitable questions about certain tools or certain practices, so that I stay in line with whatever policies are already standard among the team.

I was wondering if it may be useful for there to be a moderator-only forum where newer ones (such as myself) can ask questions, or where one can post a topic (such as "What is the best practice in dealing with posts such as this").

Comment: 2 hours and making waves?  I knew you'd be a good nomination :)

Comment: You've got a lot of demands all of a sudden.  Private forum, personal bathroom with whirlpool tub, bowl of brown M&Ms before you'll deign to answer a question...

Comment: The somafia channel is not good enough for you anymore? IS THAT IT?

Comment: Marking this as `status-complete` since we now have the Teachers' Lounge and private chat rooms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer that most of the moderator talk (except for truly, obviously *private* things like discussing details about individual users or disagreements or exploits) be [here under the moderator tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderation%20or%20moderator).

The more of this we can do in public, the better!

And for stuff that can't be, a simple email amongst the moderators on that tier should be sufficient.

> **Update:** This has now been implemented. The "Teacher's Lounge" is a private chatroom where moderators can discuss issues related to moderating.

Answer (score 2):

I have been thinking about that for a while now. It would be great if you could discuss abusive users outside of the public eye, or how to handle disruptive comments, etc.

Comment: Agreed. There are certain discussions that are bound to happen that are best to be kept away from all the attention, but there is no good central locale for that yet.

Answer (score 1):

create moderator.stackexchange.com or moderator.stackoverflow.com

why not use existing engine as stackoverflow, and I guess it shouldn't take much of the space on server, database and application could be on same machine, and if it's completely private only for mods, it could be hosted on desktop machine :)

Comment: I thought about the possibility of a stackexchange site for it, but it seemed like such a minor necessity that a simple message board would be sufficient.

Comment: I VOTE FOR PHPBB

Answer (score 1):

Kyle had a chat room going, and only 3 of us went into it.  Jeff insinuated you'd get him onto a messageboard or chat program only after the sun dried up and small squirrels became the dominant race.

I'd be cool with it, but ultimately, it's not going to be useful unless more than 3 or 4 of us are there, because we'll end up stepping on each others toes by having 3 people in agreement and a 4th being more free-flowing.  (more relevant for meta that SU)

The tendency most people seem to follow is:

1. If you know what to do, do it
2. If you don't, leave it (this is usually judgement call cases)
3. If it stays there for a day or two, clear it - no one knew what to do.

Comment: I don't think a chat program would be necessary (I am on IRC every day, but I don't really see any other mods around). More or less my idea would just be pretty simple old school BBS where we can just go and tack notes to a wall in hopes that others can see and respond.

Comment: One of the goals behind the conference was to get real-time communication among the moderators that were active during that time. If you send emails or post on a message board, the feedback you get back (assuming you get feedback at all) isn't instant, making it difficult to rapidly deal with a situation. TheTXI, if you're interested in joining I sent you an email with the details.

Comment: Actually, now that two years have passed, there is actually a special mod-only SE chatroom... where are the small squirrels, Jeff?