# Are there any topic boundaries for the private chat room Teachers' Lounge?

Tags: support, chat, meta, privacy, teachers-lounge

Because privacy and confidentiality means "what happens here, stays here", does that mean that participants there can freely voice concerns or questions that when brought to the public would be closed, such as questions regarding legal activity, legal advice, or the act of conspiring to sue the company hosting the room itself?

I can easily see why such questions would be closed, as people would use it as reference, but when all is confidential and private, are such revolutionary acts allowed?

I'm aware that I'm asking about something that is private in its essence, and giving answers to that would imply it's not private at all, but having a general idea of what's permitted to be talked about I think should be considered general knowledge. "About everything/No politics/etc" would be a perfect answer!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was created [more than ten years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6028/295232) for the following purpose:

> The "Teacher's Lounge" is a private chatroom where moderators can discuss issues related to moderating.

(Of course, like many other chatrooms in the network, sometimes we engage in discussions about other topics like cricket or unicorns.)

Other than that, it's **just about moderating**. I'm pretty sure that it would be closed down if we were to engage in conspiring to sue the company.

Comment: pineapple on pizza :)

Comment: I'd add that, by it's nature it often addresses topics more sensitive than you would want on the open site.  That's why it's private.  It's hard to say much more without risking crossing lines of privacy, but generally things seem to be pretty open to discussing whatever (related) issues present themselves.  In general, even publicly, SE generally seems pretty permissive of constructive criticism.  They might not always listen that well, but they don't tend to try to squash it either the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @DavidPostill there is no good place to talk about pineapple on pizza.

Comment: Also If I wanted to actually conspire *anything* I'd try to use something folks I am conspiring against can't see. Slack has a *perfectly* good free tier, and we could conspire *oldschool* on ***IRC*** like two ships passing in the night.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I’m guessing no-one has told you about the Usenet group?